# Allow adding bounties from the iOS & Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bounties, ios-app, mobile-app

(I was surprised I couldn't find this in an existing question, so here goes)

---

I'd like to add a bounty to a question, but I'm too lazy to go get my computer or a web browser. I like the SE app, and want to use it to do everything. I can't find the button to add a bounty to a question.

Please add this button, I really want to be able to add bounties to questions from the app.

Comment: +1, sounds convenient, improves the app, and might also bring bounties which otherwise might have been a *forgotten thought* - "I'll do it when I get home/turn on the PC/later/etc"

Comment: Why not add it to the android app too?

Comment: @Inf Because I don't really care about the android app ;) Really, it'd be a good idea to have separate posts for both versions so that they can be status-marked individually. You should go post one :D

Comment: Am too lazy to compose a feature request,  so I will leave it for someone else to do ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to add a bounty to this question, but ironically I can't do that from the iPhone app.

In the meantime, it seems like switching to the Stack Exchange mobile site is a pretty good workaround.

[image: Adding a bounty to this question]

Comment: Ironic as SO is full of programmers and they didn't add this, even more ironic when I hit "open in browser", it just takes me back to the app....