# Allow adding bounties from the Android app

Tags: feature-request, bounties, android-app

(There is an [existing feature-request for iOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243346/245167) from [Undo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/215468/undo), but none for Android, so here goes)

---

I was happy to see [a nice answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243671/245167) and wanted to award a bounty. But the SE app for Android doesn't provide a button for adding bounties. Can you please give me a button to add bounty to a post using the app?

Please add this button, using the browser to add the bounty reduces the happiness.

Comment: Bump. Is is this likely to be implemented?

Comment: @George comments don't bump anything. Meaningful edit or a bounty are the ways to properly bump. Anyway, since it's quite complicated task guess it won't be done any time soon.

Comment: @George The apps are built on top of the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and it currently doesn't allow consumers to set a bounty. I'll concur with Shadow on his timelime assumption since it would need to be implemented into the API then implemented into the app.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I never knew that comments didn't bump. I'll add a bounty next time.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3070523#3070523 /cc @George :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

**From the comments:** Since it's quite complicated task guess it won't be done any time soon. The apps are built on top of the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and it currently doesn't allow consumers to set a bounty.

[Chat transcript confirming this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3070523#3070523)